# A strange behaviour of Flow's $ElementType

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I found the next code in [flow.org](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-elementtype) (the last example of $ElementType):

```
function getProp<O: {+[string]: mixed}, P: $Keys<O>>(o: O, p: P): $ElementType<O, P> {
      return o[p];
}
(getProp({a: 42}, 'a'): number); // OK
```

and I changed it to:

```
function getProp<O: {+[string]: mixed}, P: $Keys<O>>(o: O, p: P): $ElementType<O, P> {
  return true; // no error?
}
(getProp({a: 42}, 'a'): number); // OK?
```

But there are no errors.

As I understood, the `type` of returned value is inferred from `$ElementType<O, P>` and not equivalent to `mixed` type, but should not be a `boolean` too.

Please advise me why the returned value **true** has the type `number` in this case.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When type-checking code that uses a function, Flow will only look at the function signature, and not at the body. Regardless of the fact that the body of the function always returns a `boolean`, the usage matches the signature, so this type-checks as it should.

Inside the function, Flow does the opposite. It will only type-check the body against the signature, and will not take into account how the function is actually being called. In this case, it cannot possibly know what types the elements of `O` will be, for any possible key.

The best it could do is to make sure that the type of any returned value is actually derived from a value that you pulled out of it using the supplied key, and make it an error to assume the type at all. Obviously it's not doing that, and this could be a limitation of `$ElementType`.

There are a lot of open issues in surrounding `$ElementType`, so it looks to be a little unstable, but still it might be worth [logging a bug report](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues?page=2&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+%22%24ElementType%22&utf8=%E2%9C%93) in case this is different.